# merge array using key

Tags: php, arrays

i have php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9956
            [event_url_node_id] => 2722
            [tree_id] => 2
            [node] => 2620
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9957
            [event_url_node_id] => 2722
            [tree_id] => 2
            [node] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9958
            [event_url_node_id] => 2722
            [tree_id] => 2
            [node] => 2619
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9959
            [event_url_node_id] => 2722
            [tree_id] => 1
            [node] => 5746
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9960
            [event_url_node_id] => 2722
            [tree_id] => 1
            [node] => 5952
        )

)
```

now i want to check merge array key `tree_id`
like all tree_id == 2 then its come out with `array("tree_id"=>2,"node"=>2620,4,2619);`
if tree_id == 1 then its come out with `array("tree_id"=>1,"node"=>5746,5952)`
any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
  if(array_key_exists($val->tree_id, $finalArray)) {
   $finalArray[$val->tree_id]['node'] .= ','.$val->node;
  } else {
   $finalArray[$val->tree_id]['node'] = $val->node; 
  } 
  $finalArray[$val->tree_id]['tree_id'] = $val->tree_id;
}
```

`$finalArray` will have the elements as you wished and this array will be indexed by tree_id